# split string and compare field in oracle

Tags: oracle, substring

I use Oracle DB.
I have two fields `A` and `B`.
I have to retrieve those rows where `A<>B`.
The problem is `A` could be `'12|14|15'` and `B` could be `'12|15|14'`.
So, they are actually same , only that the order of numbers is different.
How do I retrieve rows where the fields are really not equal
,like `'30|31|14'` and `'31|30|15'`, or `'22|23'` and `'22'`?

Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: Possibly because of the tool-tip @A.B.Cade (wasn't me): _"This question does not show any research effort"_

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to normalise your table. Every other solution is complex and inefficient.

The standard way of doing a proper would be to use either hierarchical queries or a pipelined table function to split the values into columns (i.e. normalise them) and then compare that way but if you have a finite number of pipes then you should be able to split on the pipe using the standard `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()` functions and compare that way.

Concatenate a pipe on to the end of the string you want to search for and, split it as per the below and then search for the string you're looking for in the second string:

```
with the_string as (
 select '|' || '12|14|15' || '|' as str1
      , '|' || '12|15|14' || '|' as str2
   from dual
        )
select substr(str1, instr(str1, '|', 1, 1), instr(str1, '|', 1, 2))
     , substr(str1, instr(str1, '|', 1, 2), instr(str1, '|', 1, 3) - instr(str1, '|', 1, 2) + 1)
     , substr(str1, instr(str1, '|', 1, 3), instr(str1, '|', 1, 4) - instr(str1, '|', 1, 3) + 1)
  from the_string
 where str2 like '%' || substr(str1, instr(str1, '|', 1, 1), instr(str1, '|', 1, 2)) || '%'
   and str2 like '%' || substr(str1, instr(str1, '|', 1, 2), instr(str1, '|', 1, 3) - instr(str1, '|', 1, 2) + 1) || '%'
   and str2 like '%' || substr(str1, instr(str1, '|', 1, 3), instr(str1, '|', 1, 4) - instr(str1, '|', 1, 3) + 1) || '%'
```

When the strings are the same length but the contents are different nothing will be returned because the content is different, when the strings are different lengths nothing will be returned because one of the "values" returned will be NULL and you cannot directly compare nulls.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18701)

As I say, normalise your database though... much simpler.

Comment: Thank you!! but, isn't it possible if the no of pipes are not same in all rows?

Comment: It's possible as long as you know the maximal number of pipes in any row @user1097217.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best solution but IMHO it's much more fun then splitting the records and then regathering them again

```
with xslt as
(select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
       <xsl:template match="/"><xsl:for-each select="//b">
         <xsl:sort select="."/><xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>') xsl from dual)

select t.*
from t, xslt
where xmltype('<r><b>'||replace(a, '|', '</b><b>')||'</b></r>').transform(xsl).getstringval() <>
xmltype('<r><b>'||replace(b, '|', '</b><b>')||'</b></r>').transform(xsl).getstringval()
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/959d1/7)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, can you please explain it a little.

Comment: First- I made it a xml by replacing the `|` with `</b><b>` (and concatenating opening and closing tags) then I use the xsl transformation to get only the values, but sorted (so `14|15` will be `1415` and `15|14` will be `1415` as well)

Comment: My original thought was to use `XMLDIFF` to check if the 2 strings wich became 2 xmls are the same or not, but apparantly it refers to the order to...